# How to solve the non-linear second order ODE $y''=\frac{x}{y}-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find a general solution to the non-linear second order ODE
$$ y'' = \frac{x}{y}-1, $$
if there is one expressible in closed form?

So far I have only found the particular solution $y(x)=x$.

Comment: We need to know what you have tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Was there anything more specific in the question? Like the general solution is in the form...

Comment: @TheCount Well, in class we mentioned some 6 types of hgher order nonlinear ODEs which we can solve, but I can't fit this one into any of those types, as they all assume that we have y' as well as y''.

Comment: @TehRod There was nothing more specific. It also wasn't stated that a general solution can be found.

Comment: This question looks like a pretty hard problem that very unlikely has an explicit solution.

Comment: you can use a numerical method to solve this

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I guess I could, but we were asked to find an general solution

Comment: What confuses me is that an obvious solution y=x was seen right away, but I can't think of a way to use that. Is it possible that it is the only closed form solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider as two members Emden-Fowler type nonlinear ODE and follow the method in http://www.sciencepubco.com/index.php/ijamr/article/download/723/628

Comment: This seems to give a possible solution, however it's full of typo-like mistakes. I'm having problems understanding how he got the z(1-xz) term in (3.4). I always get just z(1-z) without the x. As far as i can tell, later on he uses that result so it shouldn't be a typo?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Can we try introducing $ u(x,y) $ differentiating along these lines

$$ y^{\prime2} = x^2 -u(x,y) $$

$$ 2 y{\prime} y{\prime \prime} = 2 x - \left( \frac{ \partial u}{ \partial x} + \frac{\partial u} {\partial y} \frac{dy} {dx} \right) $$

So *may be* the pde that needs to be solved is

$$ 2y =\frac{\partial u} {\partial x} + \frac{\partial u} {\partial y}   \frac{dy} {dx}  $$

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm taking a course in ordinary DEs, where this problem was asked, so I am not familiar with PDEs and I am not sure what you are getting at. Can you explain a bit more?