# Solution of a second order non-linear ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was just wondering if anybody knows any references that tackle the following non-linear ODE

$$y''(x)=\frac{x}{y(x)}.$$

I'm struggling to find anything but I'm thinking that this problem must have been considered elsewhere. Perhaps not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [Emden-Fowler](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0302.pdf) type equation. Your specific case has a particular solution of $$y(x)=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} x^{3/2},$$
but even with this, the original ODE doesn't seem to be solvable.

As of writing this, Mathematica (11.2) also cannot solve it.

Comment: This might also help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103311/how-to-solve-the-non-linear-second-order-ode-y-fracxy-1/2104434#2104434

Comment: Thanks. Amazing that such a 'simple' ODE has no analytical solution!

Comment: Well, looks can be deceiving ;-) Btw, if you like my answer, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick on the left!